# Can't download from Play Store on Wi-Fi

Tags: google-play-store, download-manager

I have a BLU Vivo Air (non LTE) with 4.4.2 installed, and it has developed an issue where it will not download app updates over WiFi.  The download from the Play Store starts, but immediately goes to "download paused," and won't restart.
When I have tried looking for a solution, most people have an issue with not being able to download over mobile network, not WiFi.

I have tried clearing the cache on download manager and the play store and I have tried a factory reset.  Neither one solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a fresh restall on your router. Might be an error where your modem and router are fighting over some DNS problems.

Comment: The router is setup to use Google DNS, and other Android  devices in the house work fine with it.  Logcat does show that the reason it is pausing is network not detected.